# Which IMAP servers support both messages and subfolders in a folder?

Tags: linux, imap

I currently have a POP server for email, which is delivered to a Thunderbird client. This Thunderbird client stores email locally into a hierarchy of subfolders containing both emails and subfolders.

I now want to access this locally stored email from other clients. My first solution was to create an IMAP mailbox and move all the messages to the IMAP server. I wasn't able to do it because my IMAP server refused to create subfolders in folders already containing email.
As the original hierarchy is quite complex, I can't modify it to try to get along with this limitation.

Are there any Linux IMAP server that would accept having both messages and subfolders in a folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dovecot can do it if you use [Maildir](http://wiki.dovecot.org/MailLocation/Maildir).

Answer (score 2):

I use Dovecot and I create a subfolder in my Inbox folder (which contains a lot a mails). I am in Maildir format, and it's works well

Answer (score 0):

[UW-IMAP](http://www.washington.edu/imap/) (when configured to use specific types of back-end storage formats, such as [MIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIX_(Email))) and [Cyrus](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/) both support this, as do many others.  I believe it is more the norm to support dual-use folders than not these days, actually.